# Get a row from table in view on modal bootstrap using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am developing a CI application. My problem is I want to make a confirmation window in a modal that viewing data in a row from a table in view.

I have a view like this

PHP

```
<tbody>
 <?php
 $no = 1;
 foreach ($data_request as $data) {
 ?>

  <tr>
      <td class="sorting1"><?php echo $no++ . ". "; ?> </td>                                            
      <td class="sorting1"><?php echo $data['id_request']; ?> </td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo "$name"; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo date("d-m-Y, H:i ", strtotime($data['start_time'])); ?> </td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $data['complaint']; ?></td>                                            
      <td class="center">
         <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo $data['status_request']; ?></span>
      </td> 

       <td class="center"><?php
           echo date("d-m-Y, H:i ", strtotime($data['closing_time']));
         ?> </td>                                            

      <td  class="right">
           <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
               <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> Close
           </a>

           <a class="btn btn-success btn-setting" href="#">
               <i class="halflings-icon pencil"></i> Print
            </a>
      /td>
  </tr>

         <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

HTML

```
  <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Your Request</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This is preview :</p>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <a href="control_member" class="btn btn-primary">Print</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When users click the button print, the modal will be showing the row that was selected like just a preview ... ?

What I am supposed to do because the table is built with data from SQL table?

I guess I have solution like this :

IN MODEL :

```
SELECT * FROM tabel where id_request ...
```

OR should I just edit the view of the bootstrap modal?

Thanks...

Comment: Question is very disjointed and therefore it is difficult to understand what the specific problem is

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the req_id (unique id) of the row from table when clicked `preview`.

   `<a class="btn btn-success btn-setting" href="#" id="print" req_id="<?php echo $data['id_request']; ?>">
       <i class="halflings-icon pencil"></i> Print
   </a>`
2. Pass it to an url through ajax.

   ```
   $('#print').click(function() {

       var req_id = $(this).attr('req_id);

       var url = '<?php echo site_url("my_controller/get_row/"); ?>'+'/'+req_id;

       $.ajax({
           type: 'get',
           url: url,
           success: function (msg) {
               $('.modal-body').html(msg);
           }
       });
   });
   ```
3. And the `msg` would be a html or view from the data, which you need to write by querying from the DB in `my_controller/get_row($id)` method.
4. Sample `msg`: In `class my_controller`'s `method get_row($id)`

   ```
   class My_controller extends CI_Controller {
       public function get_row($id) {
           $row = ...; // get the row by querying from your database & further process
           echo "This is the msg : ".$row;
       }
   }
   ```

   You can also pass the `$row` to a view by `$this->load->view('template_name', ['row' => $row]);` instead of directly printing out from the method.

Comment: Mr Anindya, can you give me an example of this msg, I am totally beginer in ajax

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope, it will help. Thanks.